# gem install pam ... on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install "pam" on Windows. But starting

```
$ gem install pam
```

gives me

```
generating _pam-x64-mingw32.def
compiling pam_handle.c
In file included from pam_handle.c:5:0:
_pam.h:9:21: fatal error: version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pam_handle.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

Ruby DevKit is installed and the Installation is checked with

```
$ gem install json --platform=ruby
$ ruby -rubygems -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.load('[42]').inspect"
[42]
```

I doubt that `version.h` is unix/linux specific. Has anybody managed to install this gem on Windows?

Comment: I believe that's trying to find the Ruby "ruby.h" in the source tree.  That said - given the age and dependencies of this gem I'm guessing you'll fail later on.  `pam-ruby` depends on `ruby-pam` which I'm pretty sure requires a PAM library on either Linux or Solaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `pam` gem is not supported anymore.

https://rubygems.org/gems/pam says, that the latest release was about 10 years ago.

I'd offer you to consider using some newer replacements, and the most common advice is `Use some unix-based OS for Ruby development, instead of windows.`

Comment: this isn't the source code for the gem posted above, and this isn't really an answer and should have been a comment.

Comment: Why do you think, that this gem is not related to that OP mentioned?

Comment: I think it's this one: https://github.com/rubiojr/pam-ruby but it's hard to say - the source code link for the pam gem is dead (points to rubyforge, which died 3-4 years ago)

Comment: `gem install pam` should install `pam` gem from rubygems. And yes, it is dead. So there is no clear way even to check the source code. What other advice, except using alternative library could offer?

Comment: I am stuck with windows cause of company rules. And the code is old. Of course I would be lucky with an alternative to "pam"